# Select categories and sub-categories from the same table

Tags: sql-server, select, join, categories

I am presented with a database scenario where I have to retrieve the Products and their Packages that are in a single table. 
**NOTE:** the hierarchy is just one-level, e.g, Package1 => Cola. Package2 => Fries, Burger. Package3 => Coffee etc. i.e, two columns

I have three tables: Products, Core, Hierarchy.

**Products** holds the products and the packages which consits of other products.

***Core*** specifies whether it's a package or loose product.

**Hierarchy** specifies the Package ID

[image]

How can I select all packages and its products so that all products are grouped by their parent/package? (i.e. two columns)

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: No doubts you hv to use recursive CTE,then join product table with final CTE.Throw some sample data,then I can show you how.Also mention desire output.

Comment: Where did you get `Coffe` from?? Your table design is killing me.

Comment: If you read the description you will see "Coffee etc." is there. The dummy data in the table is not limited.

Comment: I am looking at your tables and can't get your hierarchy. You have 3 as parent of 2 - Package2 is parent of Cola. Then why in your output Packege2 has Fries and Burger and not Cola?

Comment: And Package1 is its own parent? (per first row in Hierarchy table).

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple join, since you have only 1 level of hierarchy:

```
select p2.Name as Package, 
       p1.Name as [Product(Loose)]
from Hierarchy h
join Products p1 on h.ID = p1.ID
join Products p2 on h.ParentID = p2.ID
```

Comment: you probably mean `h.ParentID = p2.ID` in the second join @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: Your query returns identical column values. No hierarchy or grouped products.

Comment: @Jnr, before posting check the solution please.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/475
Here is the fiddle. The output is exact as you want

Comment: Sorry, I used the code piece before the edit. Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri it works!